# Laravel NotFoundHttpException in define routes

Tags: php, laravel

i have this below route and that can work correctly

```
Route::get('admin/login', array('as'=>'login', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.login');
}));
```

structure of my web:

```
app
    views
        back_end
            layouts
                index.blade.php
                main.blade.php
                profile.blade.php
            login.blade.php
```

for admin i have any view for show and i want to grouping that with admin perfix. after this action and use

`http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/login` or `http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/profile` URL, i get this error:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

this is my routes:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin','before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/login', function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.login');
    });

    Route::get('/index', array('as'=>'dashboard'), function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
    });

    Route::get('/profile', function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.layouts.profile');
    });
});
```

`composer dump-autoload` command could not fix and this is that result:

```
Generating autoload files
```

how to fix this routes. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the slashes and it should work as expected

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin','before' => 'auth'), function()
    {
    Route::get('login', function() // <---------   for admin/login
    {
        return View::make('back_end.login');
    });

    Route::get('index', array('as'=>'dashboard'), function()  // <---------   for admin/index
    {
        return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
    });

    Route::get('profile', function()  // <---------   for admin/profile
    {
        return View::make('back_end.layouts.profile');
    });
});
```

ofcourse after modification of routes.php run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: i get this error, not resolve problem ` Symfony Component  HttpKernel  Exception  NotFoundHttpException `